# cloud backup routines

Tags: video, storage

I am looking for cloud backup or remote backup routines and practices that may be used for storing video.

Specifically if services or practices that offer versioning are relevant. If so, why or why not? Any examples of services you use will also be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Backblaze](https://www.backblaze.com) for this. I understand that [CrashPlan Pro](http://www.code42.com/business/) and other similar services work in the same way. Basically, you install the software (free download), do some setup, and then it just runs in the background. Every time you create a new file or modify an existing one, it will (at some later point when there's less activity on your system) just back it up to the cloud. You can usually configure it to constrain how much bandwidth it uses, which folders you do and don't want backed up, and maybe even when backups occur. And if you have a very large initial backup, they'll even send you a hard drive to back it up to. You send it back once the backup has occurred. From then on, it's incremental over the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not allowed to comment on the first post, so I'll put my comment here... I agree, pretty much all the crashplan/backblaze/etc... services do what you're looking for. I personally use SpiderOak for privacy reasons, but there are lots of options in this area.

If you want to roll your own (open source), you can go with something like Amanda (http://www.amanda.org/) or Bacula (http://www.bacula.org/) and send those backups to some cloud based service of your choice.

Comment: my main thing is how external harddrives are backed up, and how deleting my local copy for space is maintained. It looks like CrashPlan is the route for me.